# mysql/rails spreadsheet url parsing

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, parsing

Any insight into which would be the easiest way to get a spreadsheet of url's (from the same site), to be parsed and entered into a predefined mysql table. Would it be easier to use mysql or rails (which the application is built in). Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

once off quick and dirty OR > 100 records **-- sql script.**

Repeatable, re-runnable, controllable AND < 100 records. **-- rails.**